# Exoplayer Mediaplayer Android delay applying PlaybackParameters

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, media, exoplayer

I'm using Exoplayer to play a video in my application, what I want to do is change the speed of playback, for which Exoplayer provides a straightforward solution:

```
    val playbackParameters = PlaybackParameters(whateverSpeedFloat)
    exoPlayer.setPlaybackParameters(playbackParameters)
```

Now this works, but the problem I have is that the effect is not immediate, when you change the speed it takes a few frames for the actual speed to change. I guess it's because some of the frames are preloaded or buffered and the set playback parameters only affect the frames after this.

If I stop the video, and change speed from say 0.5x to 2x, then press play, it's very obvious that there is a delay in playback speed change. But, if I press stop, change the speed from 0.5x to 2x AND seek a different point in the video, and press play, it works great, there is no delay. I guess it reloads/buffers the new frames with the right playback parameters. I tried doing

```
   exoPlayer.clearVideoDecoderOutputBufferRenderer()
```

after changing speeds to try and rebuffer the frames after setting the playback parameters but it doesn't seem to change anything.
Any ideas on how to fix this? Or other video player libraries that wouldn't have this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

I still haven't found a solution, I took the problem to ExoPlayer and an issue was raised and "fixed"(https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/7982), however I'm still having the same problem, so atm I'll just get back to them and wait.

However, what was mentioned is that the delay is a know issue, and that right now there is no solution,

> Correct. We looked at options to address the delay a while ago but couldn't find a clean/general/easy to implement approach (there is no API we can use to process the audio just before the mixer, so we have to do it upstream of the audio track buffer, which introduces latency).

Instead, they suggested initialising Exoplayer with a DefaultRenderersFactory with AudioTrackPlaybackParams set to true:

```
        val defaultRenderersFactory =
        DefaultRenderersFactory(this).setEnableAudioTrackPlaybackParams(true)

        exoPlayer = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this, defaultRenderersFactory).build()
```

And this does in fact get rid of the delay (not 100% but I'd say around 80% which is good enough), but then the video speed gets all clunky and starts freezing and changing speeds every time it is paused/played or seeked to a different point.

I also tried modifying the buffering configuration @GensaGames suggested but even though I tested different configurations for a while, I never saw any change in the behaviour so discarded the solution and went to the exoPlayer repo.

I'll update this question when I finally have a working video speed changer.

Comment: My final solution was a working video speed changer which worked very smoothly, but no sound (I didn't need sound anyways). But maybe they have fixed it if you open an issue, they were very responsive to my query.

Comment: Can you explain more what is a working video speed changer? ! thank you

Comment: So, I can control the play speed of my exoPlayer, and dynamically set a speed between 10-500% of its original speed.

Comment: so i am trying something like that `player.setPlaybackSpeed(2f);` hope it works

Comment: in addition i opened the issue in github and waiting for their reply https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/10704

Answer (score 0):

I think you can decrease time of the buffering within configuration setup during `ExpPlayer` initializing. Below ex. on configuration, you can go throw documentation and check possible values.

```
/* Instantiate a DefaultLoadControl.Builder. */
DefaultLoadControl.Builder builder = new
DefaultLoadControl.Builder();

/* Maximum amount of media data to buffer (in milliseconds). */
final long loadControlMaxBufferMs = 60000;

/*Configure the DefaultLoadControl to use our setting for how many
Milliseconds of media data to buffer. */
builder.setBufferDurationsMs(
DefaultLoadcontrol.DEFAULT MIN BUFFER MS,
loadControlMaxBufferMs,
/* To reduce the startup time, also change the line below */
DefaultLoadControl.DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_MS,

DefaultLoadControl.DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_AFTER_REBUFFER_MS);

/* Build the actual DefaultLoadControl instance */
DefaultLoadControl loadControl = builder.createDefaultLoadControl();

/* Instantiate ExoPlayer with our configured DefaultLoadControl */
ExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
new DefaultRenderersFactory(this),
new DefaultTrackSelector(),
loadControl);
```

There is also good article about changing buffer time options.